# Want to update the first row value with second and vise versa, but only for one column other column values should remain same

Tags: sql

Table Name: Student

```
ID     Name 
-------------------------
1  ABC

2  PQR

3  XYZ
```

I would like to update it to:

```
ID     Name 
-------------------------
2  ABC

1  PQR

3  XYZ
```

ID column is primary key column.

I have tried the following:

```
Update student set id =case when id =1 then 2
                            when id= 2 then 1
                            else id
                            end;
```

Comment: you can not update primary column value. you have to delete all rows and truncate table, than insert all rows.

Comment: @Prashant . . . I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the databases you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Id, Id As TmpId, Name, Into #tmp from Student

Update #tmp 
Set TmpId = case when id =1 then 2 when id= 2 then 1 else id end

Truncate Table Student

Insert Into Student
Select TmpId, Name From #tmp
```

Comment: Why do you think you have to truncate the table and start over? Even if this is an identity you could just update the Name column. And if it is not an identity a simple update would work just fine.

Comment: Id should be primary field and identity enabled, truncate will do the start over and you can update your data in the temp table. update column name is a manual process, so I preferred truncate table.

Comment: But there is nothing to indicate that it is or is not an identity. And what you have is also a manual process with hard coded values. I am not saying this is wrong it just seems a bit overly complicated. And your comment on the original post stated that you feel you can't update a primary key which is not true. But you can't update an identity value.

Comment: @SeanLange As Student table has two columns one is Id and another is name so that means Id should be Primary Key as well Identity column though it is not state in the question. This the the regular practice, SO I have suggested this way. And I believe this is the write approach in all cases.

Comment: The point I am making is that if this is not an identity, a simple update statement will be sufficient. And just because a column is named Id does not mean it has to be an identity or the primary key. But is a reasonable assumption because the code the OP posted would work just fine unless it is an identity. I would actually prefer to turn identity_insert on, copy the rows to swap, delete those rows, insert and finally turn identity_insert back off instead of truncating and repopulating the entire table.